# Firebird howto count all record in table and sort max to min

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

My DB Structure

```
Table_1
Customer    |
cust_a
cust_a
cust_a
cust_c
cust_c
cust_c
cust_c
cust_b
cust_d
cust_d
cust_e
cust_e
cust_e
```

How to get result and sort it like this in firebird.

```
Table 1
customer     |    Frequency
cust_c               4
cust_a               3
cust_e               3
cust_d               2
cust_b               1
```

Note .. now i use this command it's very slow. and real data is 9800 records

```
select first 10 skip 0 distinct
    customer, (select count(*) from table_1 pdr
    where pdr.customer = prd.customer)
from
    table_1 prd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select customer, count(*) as freq
from table_1
group by customer
order by 2 desc, 1
limit 10
```